# Kaltura Playkit JS - Loading videos from other accounts

Tags: kaltura, kaltura-player

Can anyone explain to me why the following codepen Kaltura example works?
[https://codepen.io/Chuckles89/pen/zYMXXrY](https://stackoverflow.com)

It seems as though if the javascript library is loaded up which brings in the playkit & uiconfig setup/styles from that account, but it doesn't matter what other other account/entry (video) id it comes from when loading it up in the config. In the config var using any account/entry id seems to work?

The end goal is to load up that script, but have it load videos from other accounts with different partner/entry ids in the config like it is. I'm glad it works, but just wondering why it still works and if it could break down the line?